# VVV and Gulp BrowserSync outputs a useless public IP

Tags: node.js, wordpress, gulp, gulp-browser-sync, vvv-wordpress

I am running VVV, (just installed) for theme development using gulp altogether with Gulp-BrowserSync (and other npm packages).

In VVV I've created a new WP install called organic with organic.du.dev as URL. It is working fine.

In my gulpfile.js I got the following BrowserSync task:

```
gulp.task( 'browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync.init( {

    // For more options
    // @link http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/

    // Project URL.
    proxy: projectURL,

    // `true` Automatically open the browser with BrowserSync live server.
    // `false` Stop the browser from automatically opening.
    open: true,

    // Inject CSS changes.
    // Commnet it to reload browser for every CSS change.
    injectChanges: true,

    // Use a specific port (instead of the one auto-detected by Browsersync).
    // port: 7000,

  } );
});
```

When I initiate GULP (login via vagrant ssh) in the working folder everything runs and I receive the following message:

[

```
BS] Proxying: http://organic.du.dev
[BS] Access URLs:
 ----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://10.0.2.15:3000
 ----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://10.0.2.15:3001
```

The problem is that http://localhost:3000 is not accesible from Chrome or Safari and that http://10.0.2.15:3001 is a public (and useless as far as I know) IP. Running ifconfig in vagrant@vvv I receive the following prompt:

```
vagrant@vvv:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:67:05:88
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

and also the working localhost IP, which is:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4e:59:e0
          inet addr:192.168.50.4  Bcast:192.168.50.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

It took me a while to realise and find what's going on, but the problem is that I still don't understand it. I think that is an error and should be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was login via SSH into Vagrant. If gulp is executed from the computer directly it works as expected.